# Convert bash output to JSON

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

I am running the following command:

```
sudo clustat | grep primary | awk 'NF{print $1",""server:"$2 ",""status:"$3}'
```

Results are:

```
service:servicename,server:servername,status:started
service:servicename,server:servername,status:started
service:servicename,server:servername,status:started
service:servicename,server:servername,status:started
service:servicename,server:servername,status:started
```

My desired result is:

```
{"service":"servicename","server":"servername","status":"started"}
{"service":"servicename","server":"servername","status":"started"}
{"service":"servicename","server":"servername","status":"started"}
{"service":"servicename","server":"servername","status":"started"}
{"service":"servicename","server":"servername","status":"started"}
```

I can't seem to put the qoutation marks withour srewing up my output.

Comment: Could you give an example of `clustat` output, so folks can write and test a replacement for your awk script in a potentially different language?

Comment: (Adding literal quotation marks is easy enough, but handling all the other aspects of correct JSON quoting -- changing `"` to `\"`, or doubling any literal backslash on its own, or so forth is a different matter; the robust approach is to use a language with native JSON generation support).

Comment: FYI, `awk /primary/ { ... }` will incorporate the effect of `grep primary` into your `awk` script.

Comment: ...not, to be clear, that I advise using awk for the job -- [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is very much the Right Tool.

Comment: Here is the output without my add-ons:

 service:servicename  servername                   started       
 service:servicename  servername                    started       
 service:servicename  servername                    started       
 service:servicename  servername                   started       
 service:servicename  servername                    started

Comment: please edit that into the question -- that way newlines and such can be preserved.

Comment: ...btw, I don't see `primary` in that output anywhere. How is your `grep` passing any output through?

Comment: primary is in the service name but I changed as to keep the service anonymous. I should've have put servicename-primary in the example. Apologies.

Comment: You could make it `'$1 ~ /primary/ { print ... }'`, then -- that way you're not matching `primary` anywhere in the string (as grep would), but only in the service-name field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this: Instead, use [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39707444/14122), which is guaranteed to generate valid JSON as output with all possible inputs (or fail with a nonzero exit status if no JSON representation is possible).

The below is only tested to generate valid JSON with the specific inputs shown in the question, and will quite certainly generate output that *is not* valid JSON with numerous possible inputs (strings with literal quotes, strings ending in literal backslashes, etc).

```
sudo clustat |
  awk '/primary/ {
         print "{\"service\":\"" $1 "\",\"server\":\"" $2 "\",\"status\":\""$3"\"}"
       }'
```

Comment: I used the following in conjuctio with what you gave me and it had the desired output. Thanks!

    sudo clustat | grep primary | awk '{print "{\"service\":\"" $1 "\",\"server\":\"" $2 "\",\"status\":\""$3"\"}"}'

Comment: *sigh*. Rarely am I disappointed to have an answer accepted. (I quite literally wrote this to ward off other potential answers giving bad-practice-but-correct-for-constrained-input approaches, not in hopes that it would be actually adopted).

Answer (score 8):

Use `jq`:

```
sudo clustat | grep primary |
  jq -R 'split(" ")|{service:.[0], server:.[1], status:.[2]}'
```

The input is read as raw text, not JSON. Each line is split on a space (the argument to `split` may need to be adjusted depending on the actual input). `jq` ensures that values are properly quoted when constructing the output objects.

Comment: One could move the `grep` into `jq` by using a `select(test("primary"))` in the filter.

Answer (score 1):

For JSON conversion of common shell commands, a good option is [jc (JSON Convert)](https://kellyjonbrazil.github.io/jc/)

There is no parser for `clustat` yet though.

`clustat` output does look table-like, so you may be able to use the [`--asciitable` parser](https://kellyjonbrazil.github.io/jc/docs/parsers/asciitable) with `jc`.